# Big number of input neurons causes large weighed sum

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, sigmoid

I'm trying to create a neural network for my University project and have run into a problem. The network is to be used for image recognition for recognizing 320 x 200 pixel images. This means, that the number of input neurons in my network is 64.000 (320 * 200).

The problem is, that when calculating the weighed sum in each neuron in the hidden layer, I get very large numbers. When calculating the weighted sum because of this, I get results like 16000. This is my code for calculating the weighted sum, hope it clarifies what I do.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < sizes[layer - 1]; i++){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
        sum += a[j] * weights[layer - 2][i][j];
        sum += biases[layer - 2][i];
    }
    out[i] = Sigmoid(sum);
}
```

I won't get into details with the code, but the concept of it is multiplying each weight with the corresponding input value. Naturally, when I get output activations of for example 16.000 or -16.000, then running the Sigmoid function will always return 0 or 1.

My question is: Is there some way to get around this, to "normalize" the weighed sum so that the Sigmoid function will return other than 0 or 1, or is it simply a question of having a very large number of neurons in the hidden layer, or scaling down the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least three solutions to your problem:

1. **[Xavier Initialization](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiDs-3BpIvQAhVI_iwKHeWvAGMQFggdMAE&usg=AFQjCNEBTG61cvJkGroYGkLng2lx4NPE6g&sig2=ZOgc2TymHh8iIjIsOtFg1w)**: this makes your neurons avoiding not only harsh values as an input to your first layer sigmoids but also from having the same problem with a consequent layers.
2. **Using `relu` units**: the main problems with your input is a phenomenon called *vanishing gradient*. Using different activation function could overcome this issue.
3. **Applying [convolutional neural layer](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network&ved=0ahUKEwjL15PqpYvQAhXECCwKHbsEA5AQFggpMAE&usg=AFQjCNGlyukD3UmpcgF98Dlm3x0jhFLd9A&sig2=w8LvLrqnzb_HtsgueMsFKA)** which is considred as a state of the art architecture for image recognition could overcome your problem because of smaller kernel size.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have looked into convolutional neural networks now, and it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.